# Declare NGINX config for many location with variable

Tags: nginx

I have many services on the one domain.
As example:

- example.com/data_first/
- example.com/data_home/
- example.com/data_test/

and others

For all services configured same actions for use coocie auth contain over 20 lines in NGINX config.

But, I want to generalize it as one included config for easily add new services.

I write in config next directive:

```
map $request_uri $xService{
    ~^/data_(?<fp>(first|home|test))/ data_$fp;
    default 0;
}
server{
...
    if ($xService){
        include xService.conf;
    }
...
}
```

and my xService.conf contain directives:

```
location /$xService/ {
    add_header X-Pass-Return $xService;
    ... other directives include if, rewrite, proxy_pass 
}
```

but I can't use location directive inside if directive.
Is it possible to solve such a problem without listing all possible location options?

For example. I use next config:

```
location ^~ /data_first/{
    set $xService data_first;
    include xService.conf;
}
```

and other location, but I do not need to write location for any service URI.

Answer (score 0):

Why are using a map and if statements?

```
server {
   server_name example.com;
   ...
   location /data_first {
      include snippets/YOUR_COMMON_CONFIG;
      # add the stuff specific to /data_first here...
      add_header X-Pass-Return /data_first/;
      ...
   }
   location /data_home {
      include snippets/YOUR_COMMON_CONFIG;
      # add the stuff specific to /data_home here...
      add_header X-Pass-Return /data_home/;
      ...
   }
   location /data_test {
      include snippets/YOUR_COMMON_CONFIG;
      # add the stuff specific to /data_test here...
      add_header X-Pass-Return /data_test/;
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be just use simple one:

```
location ~ ^/(data_\w+)/ {
    add_header X-Pass-Return /$1/;
    ...
}
```